# How do I set default value for dropdown multiselect in angular4 and primeng?

Tags: angular

I'm having problem to set the NgModel in p-multiselect (prime-ng component) while updating the value.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiselect component has an input attribute "defaultLabel" that you can use to customize the default value displayed before selecting something, which by default is "Choose".

```
<p-multiselect
    [defaultLabel]="yourDefaultValue"
    [options]="myOptions" 
    [(ngModel)]="mySelectedOptions"
></p-multiselect>
```